# Can't make work ScrollWheel map in vim

Tags: vim, scroll, mouse, xterm

I have a little problem with mapping vim shortcuts for my mouse wheel. I can't make this work :

```
set mouse=a
set nowrap
noremap <C-ScrollWheelUp> 3zh
noremap <C-ScrollWheelDown> 3zl
```

On the other hand, the following is working (but not convenient, i just tested it to see if ScrollWheelUp/Down was working) :

```
set mouse=a
set nowrap
noremap <ScrollWheelUp> 3zh
noremap <ScrollWheelDown> 3zl
```

What is my problem ?

Comment: `<C-ScrollWheelUp>` and `<C-ScrollWheelDown>` are probably not registered by Vim in xterm. What is the output of `$ echo $TERM`?

Comment: I get : xterm-256color.  I also tried `<S-...>`.

Comment: I might add that i also tried with `map` `inoremap` `nnoremap` and others.