# Vim - unable to map multiple keys

Tags: vim, dictionary, keyboard-shortcuts

(it's a new topic whose starting point is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083641/cant-make-work-scrollwheel-map-in-vim))

To make it short, I think I can't make mapping with 2-keys combination in vim (`<key1-key2>`, or `<A-j>` for example). One-key mapping is okay.

However, 2 (or more, I didn't try) keys mapping work just fine in **gvim** !

Anyone has a clue ? Thanks for the help !

---

(if you want to know which mapping I tried, I followed [this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down). It worked when I tried with `<F_something>`, but not with the mapping of the tutorial. Again, it was okay in gvim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Vim's point of view, `<C-o>`, `<C-O>` or `<C-S-o>` can't be distinguished from each other and the situation is even more complicated with `<A-...` mappings.

While Vim allows you to do `nnoremap <C-S-o> :echo "hello"<CR>` without complaining, you'll get `hello` whether you press `<Shift>` or not.

I suggest you use `<leader>` instead: `:h mapleader`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, i managed to make it work with `,` key. I gave up using `Alt`.

Comment: However, with this trick, I could not find a way to use a shortcut in insert mode. Is there something I haven't thought about ?

Comment: Which key would you suggest to use ? I tried `,` but obviously, in visual mode it only write a coma.

Comment: My bad, I might have forgotten to source my .vimrc :/

Thanks again for your help.